# Whitelist DevOps Pipeline for Deployment Log Access

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a .NET Core based API that is hosted in an Azure VNET and is not publicly available.  To allow an Azure DevOps release pipeline to access this Azure resource, I followed the suggestion in this blog post which is to temporarily whitelist the DevOps server's IP address while performing the release:

https://keithjr.dev/development/hosted_build_agent/

While this technique works, the Deployment Center activity log in the API's app service doesn't get updated properly and doesn't show any reference to the DevOps build number like it should.

This is how I'd expect the activity log to look:

[image]

This is what actually appears, however:

[image]

An error message is displayed in the pipeline logs indicating a `403 Forbidden` error:

`2023-06-05T12:54:33.5668218Z ##[warning]Error: Failed to update deployment history. Error: Ip Forbidden (CODE: 403)`

Is there a way to get the deployment history to work properly without having to whitelist every Microsoft server IP address?

Answer (score 0):

The blog post I followed in the original post only added a whitelist record to what is considered the "Main site" in a web app's access restriction page.  In order for the Deployment Center activity logs to be properly updated as well, a whitelist record has to be added to the "Advanced tool site" as well:

[image]

To add a whitelist rule to the "Main site" (as shown in the blog post):

```
Add-AzWebAppAccessRestrictionRule -ResourceGroupName "YOUR-RESOURCE-GROUP-NAME" -WebAppName "YOUR-WEB-APP-NAME" -Name "AzureDevOpAgent$(Agent.MachineName)" -Priority 111 -Action Allow -IpAddress "$HostedIPAddress/32"
```

To add a whitelist rule to the "Advanced tool site", add the switch `-TargetScmSite` as shown in the Microsoft docs for [Add-AzWebAppAccessRestrictionRule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/add-azwebappaccessrestrictionrule?view=azps-10.0.0#-targetscmsite):

```
Add-AzWebAppAccessRestrictionRule -ResourceGroupName "YOUR-RESOURCE-GROUP-NAME" -WebAppName "YOUR-WEB-APP-NAME" -Name "AzureDevOpAgent$(Agent.MachineName)" -Priority 111 -Action Allow -IpAddress "$HostedIPAddress/32" -TargetScmSite
```